# print() not working in Python shell?

Tags: beautifulsoup

When I run this code I got from [here](https://youtu.be/PI1-1TtFz50?t=10m13s), [nothing happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avihf.png):

```
import requests
import bs4

res = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning')

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

foo = soup.select('.mw-headline')

for i in soup.select('.mw-header'):
    print(i.text)
```

Everything were installed (lxml, requests, bs4)

I cannot continue his tutorial If I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

Because `soup.select('.mw-header')` return [], this is empty array. `.mw-header` cannot be found in source website!

[image]

I recommend you use `jupyter notebook`, there will be visual results if you use it.